# Issues when using Doobie library with Oracle and Timestamp

Tags: oracle, scala, doobie

I am trying to use Doobie with oracle and I am getting some type issues:

I have a table:

```
    create table TEST
(
  CREATED_ON  TIMESTAMP(6) not null,
  A           VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  B           VARCHAR2(50) not null,
  C           VARCHAR2(50) not null,
)
```

I have a case class

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class Test(created_on: Timestamp, a:String, b:String, c:String)
```

When I try to compile Doobie complains about the Timestamp type, If I change the type to String it compiles but Inserts fail.  According to the documentation the Timestamp should be supported: https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html

Could it be something specific to Oracle?

```
Error:(36, 13) Cannot find or construct a Read instance for type:
  com.juliusbaer.quant.analytics.persistency.Test
This can happen for a few reasons, but the most common case is that a data
member somewhere within this type doesn't have a Get instance in scope. Here are
some debugging hints:
- For Option types, ensure that a Read instance is in scope for the non-Option
  version.
- For types you expect to map to a single column ensure that a Get instance is
  in scope.
- For case classes, HLists, and shapeless records ensure that each element
  has a Read instance in scope.
- Lather, rinse, repeat, recursively until you find the problematic bit.
You can check that an instance exists for Read in the REPL or in your code:
  scala> Read[Foo]
and similarly with Get:
  scala> Get[Foo]
And find the missing instance and construct it as needed. Refer to Chapter 12
of the book of doobie for more information.
      .query[Test]
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Mappings is not specific to Oracle, these are used to define mappings for our custom type like below is our case class:

```
final case class PersonId(id: Int) extends AnyVal
final case class PersonDetail(personId: PersonId, name: String)
```

According to the above case class, while we are query the table via doobie and wanted to map details with case class like:

```
sql"""select id, name from person_detail".query[PersonDetail].to[List]
```

in this case, we need to define the custom mapping for `PersonId` case class and provide that mapping in the scope. There are different ways to define mappings like `Get`, `Put`, and `Meta`. Personally I feel `Meta` is the easiest way to define mappings for `reader` and `writer` like below:

```
implicit val personIdMapping: Meta[PersonId] = Meta[Int].imap(PersonId.apply)(_.id)
```

I know the answer is late but I hope this will give some ideas and for me just a share of the knowledge.